# What are the 'Login (optional)' fields for in the GUI settings?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, full-node, nodes

There are 'Username' and 'Password' fields in the GUI settings. What are they for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These fields are used to connect to a daemon requiring a username and a password (when the *monerod* daemon was started with the *--rpc-login* option).