# How do I start the monerod daemon as a remote node with a username and password requirement to connect to it?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monerod, monero-wallet-gui, full-node, remote-access

I'd like to restrict my remote node so that only certain people can connect to it when they'd like to sync their wallet. How can I set up a username and password with my monerod daemon, so that people can't connect without the correct credentials?

Answer (score 2):

When starting your node monerod daemon, use the following start-up flag:

--rpc-login username:password

[Answer supplied by @glv](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/4536/what-are-the-login-optional-fields-for-in-the-gui-settings)